# Struts 2 post parameter from Action A to Action B

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I've got a little problem to get a post parameter in a Struts 2 Action.

My first Action loads a list:

```java
package de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action;

import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.model.Pruefungsfach;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.service.PruefungsfaecherService;

public class IndexAction implements Action {
    private PruefungsfaecherService pruefungsfaecherService;
    private List<Pruefungsfach> pruefungsfaecher;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        pruefungsfaecher = pruefungsfaecherService.listPruefungen();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Pruefungsfach> getPruefungsfaecher() {
        return pruefungsfaecher;
    }

    public void setPruefungsfaecherService(PruefungsfaecherService pruefungsfaecherService) {
        this.pruefungsfaecherService = pruefungsfaecherService;
    }

}
```

```html
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<%-- Niels Maseberg --%>

<h2>Übersicht Prüfungsfächer</h2>
<s:form>
    <table cellpadding="0">
        <caption>Liste aller Prüfungsfächer inklusive Studienrichtung und Jahrgang</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Studienrichtung</th>
                <th>Titel</th>
                <th>Jahrgang</th>
                <th>Beschreibung</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="pruefungsfaecher" status="rowstatus">
                <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true">
                    <tr class="odd">
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    <tr class="even">
                </s:else>
                    <td class="cell_radio"><s:radio name="selectedPruefungsfachId" list="#{id:''}" theme="simple"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="manipel.getPk().getStudienrichtung()"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="titel"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="manipel.getPk().getJahrgang()"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="beschreibung"/></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button">
            <s:submit value="Prüfungen anzeigen" action="pruefungslist" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

My second action gets the selectedPruefungsfachId and loads the Pruefungsfach so that I can put a hidden value in the second jsp:

```java
package de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.model.Pruefung;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.model.Pruefungsfach;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.service.PruefungenService;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.service.PruefungsfaecherService;

public class PruefungslistAction implements Action {
    private PruefungenService pruefungenService;
    private PruefungsfaecherService pruefungsfaecherService;

    private Long selectedPruefungsfachId;
    private List<Pruefung> pruefungen;
    private Pruefungsfach pruefungsfach;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PruefungslistAction.class);

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("Pruefungsfach mit der ID '" + selectedPruefungsfachId + "' wurde gewählt");
        }

        pruefungen = pruefungenService.listPruefungen(selectedPruefungsfachId);

        pruefungsfach = pruefungsfaecherService.getPruefungsfach(selectedPruefungsfachId);
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("Pruefungsfach mit der ID '" + pruefungsfach.getId() + "' wurde geladen");
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Long getSelectedPruefungsfachId() {
        return selectedPruefungsfachId;
    }

    public void setSelectedPruefungsfachId(Long selectedPruefungsfachId) {
        this.selectedPruefungsfachId = selectedPruefungsfachId;
    }

    public List<Pruefung> getPruefungen() {
        return pruefungen;
    }

    public void setPruefungenService(PruefungenService pruefungenService) {
        this.pruefungenService = pruefungenService;
    }

    public void setPruefungsfaecherService(
            PruefungsfaecherService pruefungsfaecherService) {
        this.pruefungsfaecherService = pruefungsfaecherService;
    }

    public Pruefungsfach getPruefungsfach() {
        return pruefungsfach;
    }

}
```

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<h2>Übersicht Prüfungen aus Prüfungsfach "<s:property value="pruefungsfach.getTitel()" />"</h2>
<s:form>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button">
            <!--
            <s:url id="createPruefungUrl" action="createPruefung">
                <s:param name="selectedPruefungsfachId"><s:property value="pruefungsfach.getId()" /></s:param>
            </s:url>
            <a href="${createPruefungUrl}"><s:text name="btnCreatePruefung" /></a>
            <s:url id="pruefungenHistorieActionUrl" action="pruefungenHistorie">
                <s:param name="selectedPruefungsfachId"><s:property value="pruefungsfach.getId()" /></s:param>
            </s:url>
            <a href="${pruefungenHistorieActionUrl}"><s:text name="btnPruefungenHistorie" /></a>
            -->

            <s:hidden name="selectedPruefungsfachId" value="%{pruefungsfach.id}" />
            <s:submit key="btnCreatePruefung" action="createPruefung" />
            <s:submit key="btnPruefungenHistorie" action="pruefungenHistorie" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0">
        <caption>Liste aller Prüfungen im Prüfungsfach "<s:property value="pruefungsfach.getTitel()" />"</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Dozent</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="pruefungen" status="rowstatus">
                <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true">
                    <tr class="odd">
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    <tr class="even">
                </s:else>
                    <td class="cell_radio"><s:radio name="selectedPruefungId" list="#{id:''}" theme="simple"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="datum"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="dozent.getPerson().getVorname()"/> <s:property value="dozent.getPerson().getName()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</s:form>
```

When i now click on the submit action="pruefungenHistorie" the Action PruefungenHistorieAction is called but there i don´t get the parameter "selectedPruefungsfachId"

```java
package de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.model.Pruefungsfach;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.service.PruefungsfaecherService;
import de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.service.StudentService;

public class PruefungenHistorieAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private StudentService studentService;
    private PruefungsfaecherService pruefungsfaecherService;
    private List<Integer> matrikelnummern;
    private Long selectedPruefungsfachId;
    private Integer selectedMatrikelnummer;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PruefungenHistorieAction.class);

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // Load MatrikelnummerList
        _loadMatrikelnummerList();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * showDetail Most useless comment in the world; why bother?
     */
    public String showDetail() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void validate() {
        super.validate();

        _loadMatrikelnummerList();

        if (getSelectedMatrikelnummer().equals("none")) {
            addFieldError("selectedMatrikelnummer", getText("error.no.matrikelnummer.selected"));
        }
    }

    private void _loadMatrikelnummerList() {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("PruefungenHistorieAction: Pruefungsfach mit der ID '" + selectedPruefungsfachId + "' wird geladen");
        }

        Pruefungsfach pruefungsfach = pruefungsfaecherService.getPruefungsfach(selectedPruefungsfachId);        
        matrikelnummern = studentService.getMatrikelnummerListByManipel(pruefungsfach.getManipel());
    }

    public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    public Long getSelectedPruefungsfachId() {
        return selectedPruefungsfachId;
    }

    public void setSelectedPruefungsfachId(Long selectedPruefungsfachId) {
        this.selectedPruefungsfachId = selectedPruefungsfachId;
    }

    public List<Integer> getMatrikelnummern() {
        return matrikelnummern;
    }

    public Integer getSelectedMatrikelnummer() {
        return selectedMatrikelnummer;
    }

    public void setSelectedMatrikelnummer(Integer selectedMatrikelnummer) {
        this.selectedMatrikelnummer = selectedMatrikelnummer;
    }
}
```

The attribute selectedPruefungsfachId is null and I don't understand why because in Action "PruefungslistAction" I get the parameter and in the next action I don't get the parameter...

Here is the struts.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- AUTHOR: Niels Maseberg -->

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

    <!-- Custom Theme for Struts (Author: Niels Maseberg; Base of Theme xhtml) -->
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="notendatenbank" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.templateDir" value="template" />

    <!-- Struts Package -->
    <package name="default" extends="tiles-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" default="true" />
        </result-types>

        <default-action-ref name="index" />

        <action name="index" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.IndexAction">
            <result type="tiles">index</result>
        </action>

        <action name="notenuebersicht" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.NotenuebersichtAction">
            <result type="tiles">notenuebersicht</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>                
                <param name="excludeMethods">execute</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </action>

        <action name="notenuebersichtDetail" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.NotenuebersichtAction" method="showDetail">
            <result name="input">notenuebersicht</result>
            <result name="success">notenuebersichtDetail</result>
        </action>

        <action name="pruefungslist" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.PruefungslistAction">
            <result type="tiles">pruefungslist</result>
        </action>

        <action name="createPruefung" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.CreatePruefungAction">
            <result name="input">createPruefung</result>
            <result name="success">pruefungslist</result>
            <result type="tiles">createPruefung</result>
        </action>

        <action name="pruefungenHistorie" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.PruefungenHistorieAction">
            <result type="tiles">pruefungenHistorie</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>                
                <param name="excludeMethods">execute</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </action>

        <action name="pruefungenHistorieDetail" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.PruefungenHistorieAction" method="showDetail">
            <result name="input">pruefungenHistorie</result>
            <result name="success">pruefungenHistorieDetail</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: And when you inspect the page [using firebug for example] "Übersicht Prüfungen aus Prüfungsfach ...", and look for the hidden field named `selectedPruefungsfachId`, does it have the expected id value?

Comment: Also check getters/setters for all objects.

Comment: Yes the hidden field has the expected value and if i inspect the post request via firebug there is also selectedPruefungsfachId set....Getters and setters are as you can see above in the action

Comment: Show your struts.xml file, maybe you are missing some interceptor.

Comment: Ok, i attached the struts.xml above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see by configuring your action like that

```
<action name="pruefungenHistorie" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.PruefungenHistorieAction">
   <result type="tiles">pruefungenHistorie</result>
   <interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>                
      <param name="excludeMethods">execute</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

you are using only `validation` interceptor for it.

Change this to

```
<action name="pruefungenHistorie" class="de.nordakademie.hausarbeit.action.PruefungenHistorieAction">
   <result type="tiles">pruefungenHistorie</result>
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
      <param name="validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>                
      <param name="validation.excludeMethods">execute</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

in order to use `defaultStack` of interceptors with configured `validation` interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute

```
<s:radio name="selectedPruefungsfachId" list="#{id:''}" theme="simple"/>
```

with

```
<s:radio name="selectedPruefungsfachId" list="{id}" theme="simple"/>
```

on the first JSP.

(according to http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-i-render-a-single-radio-button.html )

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I don´t have a problem wit hthe radio...it´s a problem with the submitButton key="btnPruefungenHistorie". When i click on this submit button the action does not get the selectedPruefungsfachId

Comment: Absolutely, and the "selectedPruefungsfachId " not get by the  Action is defined in... the radio ;) Post the generated html of the radio then, let's see how your id param is rendered...

Comment: The selectedPruefungsfachId is not in the radio. it´s in the hidden-field. If I inspect the hidden field with firebug it´s value is the id....so this works fine ;-)

Comment: It's in the radio in the first JSP, and in the hidden in the second; i was arguing about his correct rendering in the first one, before you shown us your struts.xml config... then it turned out that your problem was the missing Param interceptor, so just accept Alexandr right answer ;)